# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{1}{s(s-a)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am looking at an old exam about Laplace transforms which starts with the following exercise:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ denote the Laplace transform.
>   Compute the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{1}{s(s-a)^2}$$ using
>   the convolution theorem.

Firstly, I note that $\mathcal{L}[1](s) = \frac{1}{s}$ and $\mathcal{L}[t] = \frac{1}{s^2}$. Using the contraction property, we have that
$$\mathcal{L}[e^{at} t](s) = \mathcal{L}[t](s-a).$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{s(s-a)^2} = \mathcal{L}[1](s) \cdot \mathcal{L}[e^{at}t](s) = \mathcal{L}[1 * e^{at} t](s)$$
and thus
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s(s-a)^2}\right) = 1 * e^{at} t.$$
However,
$$1*e^{at} t = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{a \tau} \tau \, d\tau,$$
which firstly will not depend on $t$ anymore and secondly doesn't converge.

Wolframalpha claims the inverse Laplace transform is given by
$$\frac{at e^{at} - e^{at} + 1}{a^2}.$$
What is wrong with my calculation?

Comment: integral should be from zero to $t$. notice that $f*g(t)=\int_0^tf(u)g(t-u)du$

Comment: How so? In the corresponding lecture notes and also online, I find the definition $f*g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) g(t-\tau) \, d\tau$ with the remark that if $f, g$ are only defined on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, we can instead compute $\int_0^t f(\tau) g(t-\tau) \, d\tau$. However, the functions $f(t) = 1$ and $g(t) = t e^{at}$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}$, no?

Comment: just by definiton watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW4Reburjpc

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform is defined only for functions $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{C}$. Therefore, if I write an expression such as
$$\mathcal{L}[e^{at} t](s),$$
implicitly, $t \mapsto e^{at} t$ is only defined on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (or defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but $0$ for $t < 0$). On that domain, the convolution reduces to
$$\int_0^t f(\tau) g(t-\tau) \, d\tau,$$
which for this exercise yields the correct solution. Thanks to daulomb's comments which pointed me to the right direction.